# GWT 2.2.0 and 3rd party MVP frameworks

Tags: gwt, frameworks

GWT 2.2.0 brings radical changes in GWT: Activities, Places. Many frameworks like gwt-mvp, etc. work on older features of GWT like RPC, MVP, etc.

Are these third party frameworks deprecated? Are there any frameworks that emerged since GWT 2.2.0?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The third party frameworks are not automatically deprecated because google duplicated their functionality, but I will definitely prefer features built right into GWT to external libraries.  The GWT team has shown a dedication and reliability to the product that I've come to trust - and I don't have time to build up that trust for 3rd parties if I don't have to!

That said, there are still some rough edges to the features that GWT has just released, and some 3rd-party frameworks may be more mature than the GWT counterparts.  My feeling is that, for things I'm learning from scratch, I might as well learn the GWT things.  For libraries I've been using for a long time (gwt-log, gwt-dnd), even if Google builds those straight into GWT, they will need some pretty compelling features to get me to switch my momentum.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! So apart from gwt-log, gwt-dnd, are there any other libraries that you prefer against GWT features? Perhaps GWTP, or something else? I'm specifically interested in something that would be up-to-date and compare with GWT 2.2.0 features like Activities, Places, etc.